# String prototype in node v0.10.25 does not have 'endsWith'

Tags: javascript, node.js

When i tried to check for a string pattern using endsWith in node server versioned v0.10.25, it threw an error,

```
Object ''''''' has no method 'endsWith'
```

Then i found out from this link, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith, that String.prototype.endsWith will come only from ECMA6.
So, what ecma version node v0.10.25 has implemented? which future release of nodejs, i can expect to be ECMA6 compliant?

Comment: Would this answer on a similar question help: [Ecmascript 6 support on Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26693835/808431)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ here you can find the compatibility chart for `ecma-script-6`.

and read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13352093/3556874.
You can activate the node harmony flag node this way `--harmony app.js`, to make node compatible with strings `endsWith`

Answer (score 5):

It's obvious that if not ES6, it would be implemented in ES5, or the current iteration of jaavacript. Also instead of waiting for it, you could write your own

```
String.prototype.endsWith = String.prototype.endsWith || function(str){
   return new RegExp(str + "$").test(str);
}
```

Comment: This would be better to use :)